# Sending multiple objects using javascript and ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've created code that takes an object and sends it from one web page, in javascript, to another. 
I use Ajax and the POST method to send the object, and I currently use POST on the second page to get the data in PHP and send it back to a database.
Currently it works when I try send one object, but I'm trying to find a way to send multiple objects in one go.

I'm trying to use a for loop, I loop through an array containing the objects and attempt to send one at a time.
Currently only the first item in the array makes its way to the database and I'm unsure why.

Below is the code using Ajax to send:

```
        for (i = 0; i < objSend.length; i++) {
            //objSend is the array containing the objects
            console.log("i",i);
            console.log(objSend[i]);

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url : "map_process_test.php",
                data: objSend[i],
                success : function(data){
                    console.log("Sent/Done");
                },
                error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
                    alert(thrownError);
                }

            });


        }
```

The console returns "Sent/Done" every time, but nothing else is found in the database.
Below is the code from the second page that receives the data

```
$lat = $_POST["pin_lat"];
    $lng = $_POST["pin_lng"];
    $pin_id = $_POST["pin_id"];
    $pin_number = $_POST["pin_number"];
    $pin_text = $_POST["pin_text"];
    $pin_title = $_POST["pin_title"];
    $project_id = $_POST["project_id"];


    $results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_project_coords(pin_id, pin_number, pin_lat, project_id, pin_lng, pin_title, pin_text) VALUES ('$pin_id','$pin_number','$lat','$project_id','$lng','$pin_title','$pin_text')");
    echo("DONE 2 ");
```

I've tried using Async set to both true and false, and neither has made a difference.
Thanks for any help

Comment: One suggestion is to add more logging to the PHP code.  Can you confirm that the PHP script is being executed?

Comment: You also need to read up on sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the object like this:

```
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url : "map_process_test.php",
            data: { data_from_javascript: JSON.stringify(objSend)},
            success : function(data){
                console.log("Sent/Done");
            },
            error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }

        });
```

And then server side using php try:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data_from_javascript']);

foreach($data as $entry)
{
  $lat = $entry["pin_lat"];
$lng = $entry["pin_lng"];
$pin_id = $entry["pin_id"];
$pin_number = $entry["pin_number"];
$pin_text = $entry["pin_text"];
$pin_title = $entry["pin_title"];
$project_id = $entry["project_id"];


$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_project_coords(pin_id, pin_number, pin_lat, project_id, pin_lng, pin_title, pin_text) VALUES ('$pin_id','$pin_number','$lat','$project_id','$lng','$pin_title','$pin_text')");
echo("DONE 2 ");
```

Comment: That could work, but you would have to send the json data as the value with the corresponding key like: `data: { 'data_from_javascript': JSON.stringify(objSend) },`. Otherwise you would have to read the raw input instead of accessing `$_POST`.

Comment: True. Forgot that part.

Comment: Edited. @McDonough, I'd also suggest using `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query` since the latter is being deprecated soon.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and I think I just need to sort out the foreach next!

It sends the amount of objects in the array, but for some reason it repeats 

the first object each time! I'll play around with it, and yeah I plan on adding sql security once basic functionality is done.

Comment: for some reason when I use JSON nothing seems to be sent back to the database, and that is with the decode on the server side as well.

Posting the data without using JSON seems to half work, as mentioned in my above comment

Comment: Are you using `or die(mysql_error($db)` after your mysql query function?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to adapt the backend code to correctly loop over the results, but I think you can send your whole object in one go:

```
data: { 'everything': objSend },
```

That would get your a multi-dimensional `$_POST['everything']` array that you can loop over, similar to when you give your form elements names like `name="my_name[key1][key2]"`.

You could of course also send the whole package as a string and parse that on the server:

```
 data: { 'json': JSON.stringify(objSend) },
```

And then you could get the original structure back using something like `json_decode($_POST['json'])`.